# Dynamic links of libraries with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, lib

**Case 1:**

I had 3 different projects linked like this with **gcc** :

```
ProjectA.so  <--- Dynamic link --- ProjectB.so <--- Dynamic Link --- ProjectC (App)
```

To use B, the C project just had to link B dynamically (-lProjectB).

**Case 2:**

Then I splitted the lib A into 2 so/DLLs : A1 and A2 (with A2 using A1).
Here, if either B or C link only A2, it's not working anymore.

```
ProjectA1.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

So my question is : **Do we have to link a lib used internally by the lib we link ?**

Why sometimes it works (case 1) and sometimes not (case 2) ? Is there a general rule about this ??

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You may want to drop the hyperlink tag and instead tag your compiler.

Comment: "Do we have to link a lib used internally by the lib we link ?" - Assuming all libraries being shared, no, you needn't to link with a library using internally. It seems something wrong with your code (C++ or `CMakeLists.txt`). Please, **add the code** into the question post.

Comment: Ok I found something.

Actually in the same time I changed something else.
A class `Derived` in ProjectB inherits from a class `Base` in ProjectA.

In the C project, I used before a shared_ptr on `Derived`. Now it's a simple object.
Can it explain that we need to link ProjectA too ?

Comment: Potentially yes, @Maluna34, if in project C you use a pointer to `Derived` (including any flavor of smart pointer), then it is possible that project C contains direct calls to `Base` methods or destructors, which reside in project A.  That would constitute a direct dependency on A, requiring its DSO to be included in the link.  That's particularly likely if `Derived` has inline methods or an inline destructor that invokes `Base` methods.